# Mocking completable future

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am trying to create unit test for the following code.  The code utilizes AWS Java 2 SDK.  The code calls selectObjectContent in S3AsyncClient class which returns a CompletableFuture  (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3AsyncClient.html). My test is returning null pointer exception while invoking future.get()

Here is the method I want to unit test.

```
    public <T> Collection<T> queryWithS3Select(
        List<String> s3Keys,
        String s3SelectQuery,
        InputSerialization inputSerialization,
        Class<T> modelObject,
        Comparator<T> comparator
    ) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, IOException {
        TreeSet<T> collection = new TreeSet<>(comparator);

        List<SelectObjectContentRequest> selectObjectContentRequest =
            buildS3SelectRequests(s3Keys, s3SelectQuery, inputSerialization);

        S3SelectContentHandler s3SelectContentHandler = new S3SelectContentHandler();

        StringBuilder selectionResult = new StringBuilder();

        for (SelectObjectContentRequest socr : selectObjectContentRequest) {
            CompletableFuture<Void> future = s3AsyncClient.selectObjectContent(socr, s3SelectContentHandler);
            future.get();

            s3SelectContentHandler.getReceivedEvents().forEach(e -> {
                if (e.sdkEventType() == SelectObjectContentEventStream.EventType.RECORDS) {
                    RecordsEvent response = (RecordsEvent) e;
                    selectionResult.append(response.payload().asUtf8String());
                }
            });
        }

        JsonParser parser = objectMapper.createParser(selectionResult.toString());
        collection.addAll(Lists.newArrayList(objectMapper.readValues(parser, modelObject)));
        return collection;
    }
```

My unit test so far.  Running this code I get null pointer exception at future.get() line above.  How can I use the mock s3AsyncClient to return a valid future?

```
    @Mock
    private S3AsyncClient s3AsyncClient;

    @Test
    public void itShouldReturnQueryResults() throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        List<String> keysToQuery = List.of("key1", "key2");

        InputSerialization inputSerialization = InputSerialization.builder()
                .json(JSONInput.builder().type(JSONType.DOCUMENT).build())
                .compressionType(String.valueOf(CompressionType.GZIP))
                .build();

        Comparator<S3SelectObject> comparator =
                Comparator.comparing((S3SelectObject e) -> e.getStartTime());


        underTest.queryWithS3Select(keysToQuery, S3_SELECT_QUERY, inputSerialization, S3SelectObject.class, comparator );

    }
```

Here is the S3SelectContentHandler

```
public class S3SelectContentHandler implements SelectObjectContentResponseHandler {

    private SelectObjectContentResponse response;
    private List<SelectObjectContentEventStream> receivedEvents = new ArrayList<>();
    private Throwable exception;

    @Override
    public void responseReceived(SelectObjectContentResponse response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    @Override
    public void onEventStream(SdkPublisher<SelectObjectContentEventStream> publisher) {
        publisher.subscribe(receivedEvents::add);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionOccurred(Throwable throwable) {
        exception = throwable;
    }

    @Override
    public void complete() {}

    public List<SelectObjectContentEventStream> getReceivedEvents() {
        return receivedEvents;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you create mocks with mockito it creates a dummy class which always returns null for all methods. You also need to mock the actual method calls so they return something useful (usually mocks as well). Something like:

Mockito.when(s3AsyncClient.selectObjectContent(any()).thenReturn(<the future you wanna do work with>);

Answer (score 0):

I will share unit test for similar functionality and show you how to work with completable future when your code has `.join()` to continue the execution

**Code under test**

```
private final S3AsyncClient s3AsyncClient;

public long getSize(final S3AsyncClient client, final String bucket, final String key) {
    return client.headObject(HeadObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucket).key(key).build()).join().contentLength();
  }
```

and in this code the `client.headObject()` returns the `CompletableFuture<HeadObjectResponse>` which we are going to mock and test in **Unit Test as shown below**

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Verify getSize returns the size of the given key in the bucket")
void verifyGetSizeRetunsSizeOfFileInS3() {
CompletableFuture<HeadObjectResponse> headObjectResponseCompletableFuture =
        CompletableFuture.completedFuture(HeadObjectResponse.builder().contentLength(20000L).build());

when(s3AsyncClient.headObject(headObjectRequestArgumentCaptor.capture()))
        .thenReturn(headObjectResponseCompletableFuture);

  long size = s3Service.getSize(s3AsyncClient, "somebucket", "someFile");

assertThat(headObjectRequestArgumentCaptor.getValue()).hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("bucket", "somebucket")
        .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("key", "someFile");

assertThat(size).isEqualTo(20000L);
}
```